# How to force account selection when using social provider login in Lock

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, auth0, google-account

I am having trouble clearing the last login when using social providers.

Currently using Lock with the following options:

```
var options = {
   rememberLastLogin: false,
   auth: {
      sso: false,
      redirect: false
   }
};

var lock = new Auth0Lock('clientID', 'account.auth0.com', options);
```

The issue is that when executing the next steps it always logins with the same account:

1. Call `lock.show`
2. Select social login provider (Google)
3. Attempt login with account A *[non authorized account]*
4. Lock shows "You are not allowed to access this application." *[expected result]*
5. Click Google button again and it still tries to log into the same account A *(Lock does not offer a way to try different login from same social provider)*
6. Close Lock and reopen it
7. Click Google button and it still uses same login account A *(no option to enter new account)*

What can I do to be able to select a different account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a social login provider the automatic sign-in is handled by the provider in question. Disabling the `sso` option and `rememberLastLogin` will mean Auth0 will not try to login you automatically or provide any information about who login for the last time.

When you login with Google the first time, Google created a session and next requests will automatically use that session by default.

However, Google supports an **option that will allow you to choose the behavior you want**, in this case it seems you want for **the user to be able to select another account**, which can be accomplished by passing the following option `prompt=select_account` (see other options [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#re-consent)) in the Google login request.

You can achieve this in Auth0 [Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) by providing this option in the [`auth.params`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#params-object-) object. Updated example below:

```
var options = {
    rememberLastLogin: false,
    auth: {
        sso: false,
        redirect: false,
        params: { prompt: 'select_account' }
    }
};

var lock = new Auth0Lock('clientId', '[tenant].auth0.com', options);
```

Comment: Wow that is fantastic, and is the correct answer where the Auth0 team gave an incorrect (incomplete so did not work) answer on their forum. Thanks so much for your insight, really appreciated.

Comment: Well, technically, the Auth0 team did end up solving the issue as I'm also an Auth0 engineer. :) Most important, is that you got your problem solved, happy to be of assistance.

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you successfully authenticate using `{ prompt: 'select_account' }` instead of receiving `expires_at` you will receive `expires_in`. Then we should calculate `expires_at` as described here: https://auth0.com/docs/guides/migration-legacy-flows . Is this solution ok @JoãoAngelo ?

Comment: The docs now always refer you to use 'auth0-js' instead of auth0lock -- how do we convert if we are just using `auth0.authorize()` to signin?

Answer (score 1):

Or if you use Auth0.WebAuth then you need to pass param to authorization call:

```js
auth0Instance.web.authorize({
  prompt: 'select_account'
})
```